# Why is 11==011 returning false?

Tags: c++, c, boolean

I am puzzled at what my program outputs:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    if(11==011)
        printf("True");
    else
        printf("False");
}
```

The output is `"False"`.

Comment: For the same reason that programmers think Halloween and Christmas are on the same date: Oct 31 == Dec 25.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In C a number beginning with `0` is considered [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), i.e. base 8. So `011` is actually `9`.

> 6.4.4.1
>
> A decimal constant begins with a nonzero digit and consists of a
>   sequence of decimal digits.  **An octal constant consists of the preﬁx 0**
>   optionally followed by a sequence of the digits 0 through 7 only.

Comment: What is an octal number ? could you explain ?

Comment: @c.adhityaa An octal number is a number with _base 8_ (ie no digit is greater than 7) instead of the normal _base 10_. This means that the sequence of counting is ...5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20...

Comment: octal number is a number expressed in base 8, like hexadecimal is expressed in base 16 and binary in base 2. Basically, you express numbers using only 8 digits (0..7). The rules are exactly the same as decimal (base 10) so after 7 we have 10 which is 8 in decimal. and after 10 we have 11 which is 9. There is a lot of theory behind number bases.

Comment: @c.adhityaa: An octal number is a number in base 8, or in other words, a number that is represented with only 8 numerals (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7). Think of decimal, there we have 10 numerals (0-9), and it represents a number. Different bases (binary, hex, octal, decimal, 64) are very useful, and you should probably devote some time to learning them.

Comment: @Linuxios Where are they useful ? And yeah, I will start learning them.

Comment: @c.adhityaa:  Octal numbers are significant because a single octal digit maps to exactly 3 binary digits, it is sometimes convenient to use octal so that it is easy to determine the bit pattern.  Similarly hexadecimal (base 16) digits map to 4 binary digits and are perhaps more common and useful because computer memory and registers are normally multiples of 8 bits, and *binary-coded decimal* can be represented directly in hex.  C supports three literal numeric representations decimal, octal and hex.  So 9 == 011 == 0x09, and 11 == 013 == 0x0b.

Comment: @c.adhityaa: Hex is used to represent most specifically sized values, as 2 ex digits is exactly one byte. Binary because it is the internal representation, and base 64 is used for some encoding.

Answer (score 5):

The following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << 11 << endl;
    cout << 011 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces the output:

```
11
9
```

This is because prefixing a number with a 0 produces an octal number.

So,

```
011 (base 8) = 1*8^1 + 1*8^0 = 9 (base 10)
```

This would explain why your conditional evaluates as `false`.

Comment: Hey, why'd you edit out the "Exactly why that is, I haven't a clue, but it does explain why your condition returns false." part? That was the only difference between your answer and the correct one...

Comment: Because, I learned why the output was 11 and 9. And felt an explanation would be more appropriate than something akin to "I don't know why this is."

Comment: Well if you didn't know, perhaps you shouldn't have answered, no? Bookmark the question and follow it to learn something new... don't write an answer that re-iterates the problem, wait for a correct one and then edit yours with the correct explanation. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Before this question was edited, the OP was confused as to why the program was printing "False". I illustrated why, (i.e. 9 != 11).

Answer (score 2):

`011` is treated as an [`octal`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) number, not [`decimal`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal). The conversion of `011` ( octal ) to decimal is `9`. So is `11` equal to `9`? No.

**Edit: what are octal numbers?**

The octal numeral system, or oct for short, is the `base-8` number system, and uses the digits `0` to `7`.Octal numerals can be made from binary numerals by grouping consecutive binary digits into groups of three (starting from the right). For example, the binary representation for decimal `74` is `1001010`, which can be grouped into `(00)1 001 010` – so the octal representation is `112`.

Answer (score -1):

It's about numerical bases. In C++, some numerical bases are denoted with unique prefixes for more comfortable usage (decimal has none), e.g. hex (16) is 0x: 0xFACE8D, octal (8) has 0: 011

[This article](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/hex/) can help you understand it better.